# Netty Client Connection

Tags: netty

I have a question when creating a client connection in netty.

```
Configuring a channel
Options are used to configure a channel:

 ClientBootstrap b = ...;

 // Options for a new channel
 b.setOption("remoteAddress", new InetSocketAddress("example.com", 8080));
 b.setOption("tcpNoDelay", true);
 b.setOption("receiveBufferSize", 1048576);
```

Here, why don't we have a bind method that binds the channel to the port (at client side) from where the client connection is initiated ? 
the only thing we need to provide is to give the server address and port as below:

```
channel = bootstrap.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port));
```

does this create a new channel at client side or server side? what port this channel is binded in client side?

We do the binding when doing a server side BootStrap as below

```
 ServerBootstrap b = ...;
 channel = b.bind(b.getOption("localAddress"));
```

I am confused and not able to understand from which port the client is sending the data to server and what channel is used?

Answer (score 5):

You should use `ClientBootstrap.connect(remoteAddress, localAddress)` to specify the local address of the socket you are going to create.  Alternatively, you can call `ClientBootstrap.bind(localAddress).sync()`, and then call `ClientBootstrap.connect(remoteAddress)` to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a client connection using `connect(SocketAddress remoteAddress))` you create a channel on the client side.
The connect method binds on a local address and then connects to a remote address. when not specifying a local address in the connect method, the method will bind on the local ip and a random port.
if you wish to decide which local port to use, you need to use the `connect(SocketAddress remoteAddress, SocketAddress localAddress)` method.